# React - Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a demo [available on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nuc5rk?file=index.tsx). This is very pseudo code and my actual code is a lot more complicated.

I have three components loaded into `index.tsx`. Each component has a conditional that checks the boolean above. My actual code checks data from a GraphQL call.

If the component is shown I want to store the text. I'm trying to do this with `useState`. So, if the About section is shown add 'About' to the `nav` state.

I'm getting the error:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'
```

Can anyone explain this error, is it possible to do this?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import About from "./About";
import Products from "./Products";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState([])

  const about = true;
  const products = true;
  const contact = true;

  return (
    <div>
      {about && (
        setNav([...nav, 'About'])
        <About />
      )}
      {products && (
        setNav([...nav, 'Products'])
        <Products />
      )}
      {contact && (
        setNav([...nav, 'Contact'])
        <Contact />)}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If your code checks data from a GraphQL call, you should update the `nav` state from there (right after you received the response) and display the components based on that state, not the other way around.

You can use the `useEffect` hook to grab the response and update your state. I would also use an object instead of an array to store the nav state (it's easier to update its values).

```js
function App() {
  const [nav, setNav] = React.useState({
    about: false,
    contact: false, 
    products: false,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // make the graphQL call here and based on the response update the state:
    
    const graphqlResponse = {
      about: true,
      contact: false,
      products: true,
      // ... others
    }
    
    setNav({
      about: graphqlResponse.about,
      contact: graphqlResponse.contact,
      products: graphqlResponse.products,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {nav.about && <About />}
      {nav.products && <Products />}
      {nav.contact && <Contact />}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({nav}, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

function About() { return <h2>About</h2> }
function Contact() { return <h2>Contact</h2> }
function Products() { return <h2>Products</h2> }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The graphql calls are different calls so its not one graphql call like in your example. The components are added to the page and I wanted some way to create a nav from the components that are displayed

Comment: I'll try a new question

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
{ about && setNav(["About", ...nav]) && <About /> }
{ products && setNav(["Product", ...nav]) && <Products /> }
{ contact && setNav(["Contact", ...nav]) && <Contact /> }
```

Comment: This give the error `An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xky8ql?file=index.tsx